# React Native Color Style

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

Here I have attached one image. That bar has a dark and light blue color mix according to image.how can I achieve that task?

[image]

Comment: You need to add a linear gradient from `dark blue` to `light blue`

Comment: Thanks. That should be the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) library:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
     width: 40px, height: 250px
  }
})

...

render() {
  <LinearGradient colors={['#319CF7', '#BDE0FB']} style={styles.linearGradient} />
}
```